# Modificar parámetros de inicio MS SQL SERVER desde consola

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema con SQL Server 2012+ que hizo un cambio en los `Identity` y salta de a 1000 con cada reinicio, en [este articulo](http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2014/2/13/how-to-solve-identity-problem-in-sql-2012/) se explica bien cómo desactivar el indicador de rastreo 272.

Me gustaría saber si se puede hacer un .bat que por medio de consola de SQL Server desactive el indicador.

Comment: Por lo que entendí el flag se configura cuando se inicia la instancia de SQL server, no se si se puede configurar posteriormente al inicio del servicio

Comment: podría cambiarlo y reiniciar el servicio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para activar un *trace flag global* usa el siguiente comando:

```
dbcc traceon (272,-1)
```

`traceon`, habilita el *trace flag* 272, es la bandera que menciona la página que incluiste, `-1` es para que sea global en todo el servidor, no solo en la sesión.

Si deseas desabilitarlo usa:

```
dbcc traceoff (272,-1)
```

Para ver que este corriendo utiliza:

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS(-1);
```

Como con cualquier *traceflag*, hay que revisar bien antes de implementar y estar seguros que resolverá el problema.